# Valid YubiKey configuration for kraken.com?

Tags: kraken.com, yubikey

I am getting **"Bad OTP"** and **"Bad Data"** when trying to set my **YubiKey** as 2FA option on https://www.kraken.com.

How to configure the YubiKey token so it is accepted as valid 2FA device?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Kraken.com** is using **Yubico OTP** functionality (Yubico AES). It means that kraken.com is using Yubico validation server to verify YubiKey tokens. This functionality is available with all **YubiKey** tokens (**not** blue Security Key - these are missing this fuctionality).

Your token must have valid Yubico OTP configuration that is also stored at the Yubico validation servers. All tokens are pre-configured by default, but when user has changed the token settings, he may also override this configuration and later, Yubico OTP functionality does not work. And this is the reason why your token is not working with https://www.kraken.com.

See 
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115954/relative-merits-of-yubico-otp-vs-oath-hotp

Follow steps described in https://www.yubico.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/YubiKey_for_YubiCloud_ConfigGuide_en.pdf:

- Install YubiKey Personalization Tool (YPT)
- Setup Yubico OTP in quick mode on slot 1
- Upload the configuration to Yubico (button "Upload to Yubico" in YPT)
- This will open and prefill form at https://upload.yubico.com/, you just need to touch to token and submit and wait
- Once uploaded, your token should be valid for https://www.kraken.com 2FA